# Replacing Column Header Text using Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to replace the headers in Columns B and C with a different header text with the following code:

```
   Columns("B").Replace What:="PN-ASSIGN", _
                         Replacement:="SERV BAL.", _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         MatchCase:=False, _
                         SearchFormat:=False, _
                         ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("C").Replace What:="MISC COST", _
                         Replacement:="EQUIP BAL.", _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         MatchCase:=False, _
                         SearchFormat:=False, _
                         ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But when I try to use it, the code doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The code worked for me. I wonder what I am missing to replicate the problem? Are they merged cells?

Comment: Qualify your sheet - your macro could be running on the wrong sheet if you have more than one on your book

Comment: Most likely the contents of the cell you are actually referring to does not match the `What:=` parameter.  Whether this is because of the actual content (non-printing characters or spaces), or the column worksheet reference, is hard to tell from the information you provide.  Perhaps if you upload a worksheet that demonstrates the problem to some public site (with sensitive information removed) and post a link here (by editing your question), you will obtain better assistance.

Comment: Yeah, it was running on the wrong sheet. Haha Dumb mistake, Thanks for the help guys! Should I use a With statement or should I just do something like:

Dim ws as Worksheet
ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Columns("B").Replace

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify your sheet as it sounds like your macro is relying on the Active Sheet which is bad practice. You can use a `With` statement if you are referring to you `ws` multiple times. Also, you do not need to indicate all the options for the `.Replace` method. If you do not specify, they default to false. The below code should be sufficient as is.

Also, `Option Explicit` for good measure

```
Option Explicit

Sub Headers()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("B:B").Replace "PN-Assign", "Serv Bal.", xlPart
ws.Range("C:C").Replace "MISC COST", "EQUIP BAL.", xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!